# The rectangle didn't draw through SQLDataReader while clause

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, drawrectangle

Why the rectangle didn't draw? Is there any mistake in my code? I try to create a rectangle through SQLDataReader while clause..

```
private void PrintsDoc (object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat ();
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;

    Font fontStyle = new Font ("Times New Roman", 30);
    Font fontStyle2 = new Font ("Times New Roman", 10);
    g.DrawString ("Trade Confirmation", fontStyle, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, sf);
    g.DrawString ("\n\n\nTrade Date: " + dt + "\nPrint Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString (), fontStyle2, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, sf);

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=WORKERCOMP\\SQLEXPRESS;" + "Database=database;" + "User ID=uid;" + "Password=pwd;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;");
    conn.Open ();

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'dbo.TRADE'", conn);
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
    while (rdr.Read ()) {
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle (new Point (40 + i, 250), new Size (200, 25));
        g.DrawRectangle (Pens.Black, rec);
        g.DrawString (rdr.GetString(0 + j), fontStyle2, Brushes.Black, rec, sf);
        i = i + 215;
        j = j + 1;
    }

    e.HasMorePages = false;
    conn.Close ();
}
```

Comment: Go debugging. Place breakpoints, step through your code, inspect your variable. If the `while()` isn't executed, your query yields no results.

Comment: Hey, I've tested that SQLCommand in SQL Server Management Studio, and it has results.. So I think the while clause should be running.. But why the rectangle didn't draw

Comment: Are you sure you tried it in SSMS? TABLE_NAME doesn't include SCHEMA_NAME.

Comment: No, don't guess. Debug.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who voted down my question. I've just learned programming for about couple months, and I think that votedown shows you didn't appreciate someone that willing to learn.

Comment: I am not one of downvoters, and you are right this downvoting on stackoverflow sucks. Especially when they do it just because they don't understand the question (while others might).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void PrintsDoc (object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat ();
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;

    Font fontStyle = new Font ("Times New Roman", 30);
    Font fontStyle2 = new Font ("Times New Roman", 10);
    g.DrawString ("Trade Confirmation", fontStyle, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, sf);
    g.DrawString ("\n\n\nTrade Date: " + dt + "\nPrint Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString (), fontStyle2, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds, sf);

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=database;Trusted_Connection=yes;"))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TRADE'", conn))
    {
    conn.Open ();
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader ();
    while (rdr.Read ()) {
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle (new Point (40 + i, 250), new Size (200, 25));
        g.DrawRectangle (Pens.Black, rec);
        //g.DrawString (rdr.GetString(0 + j), fontStyle2, Brushes.Black, rec, sf);
        g.DrawString ((string)rdr["COLUMN_NAME"], fontStyle2, Brushes.Black, rec, sf);
        i = i + 215;
        j = j + 1; // what is the purpose of j?
    }

    e.HasMorePages = false;
    conn.Close ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried the TABLE_NAME in SSMS and works fine. I use j to increment rdr.GetString(column no.)

Comment: It should be GetString( 0 or 1 - constant ) then.